# How to judge a torch.tensor dtype is int or not?

Tags: pytorch

I want to check a `Tensor` convert from an image is normalized or not, i.e. the dtype is `int` or `float`. Is there convenient way to achieve this goal? I **do not** want an enumerated condition check like `a.dtype == torch.int or a.dtype == torch.int32 or a.dtype ==torch.uint8 ....` . Or is there another way to check an image tensor normalized or not?

Comment: Torch dtypes have an `is_floating_point` property that would appear to be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72253473/how-to-judge-a-torch-tensor-dtype-is-int-or-not#comment127653778_72253473), you can use [`torch.is_floating_point`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.is_floating_point.html#torch.is_floating_point) to check your tensor:

```py
if torch.is_floating_point(my_tensor):
  # the tensor is "normalized"...
else:
  # the tensor is an integer and needs to be normalized...
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answers and comments, [`torch.is_floating_point`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.is_floating_point.html#torch.is_floating_point) will cover most situations.

However, do note that `torch.is_floating_point` will return `False` for complex dtypes, which are not integers. It seems that, as of now, PyTorch is missing a `torch.is_integer` check.

As a workaround to cover more cases than just `int` VS `float`, one may consider using the following condition:

```py
not torch.is_floating_point(my_tensor) and not torch.is_complex(my_tensor)
```